# Linux iptables usage route outgoing traffic

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

I have a problema, i want to enter a site that blocks by default all ips, except some ones, my server ip is not allowed, but i have another server ip allowed, so i have done a local ssh port forwarding localhost:81 to this site, works fine, if i enter on my non allowed server and i do:
lynx localhost:81
I see perfect site.

My problem is, i have to see the same if i enter on shell:
lynx abc.com

(keep in mind that abc.com is the site that dont allow traffic from every ip)
Si what i want is that abc.com redirect it to localhost:81
Instead of abc.com i can route all traffic of the ip hosting that site, dont have to be FQD routing, anyone know how to do this with iptables, the routing process?

Thanks

Comment: @Michael: that's not a programming related question. Anyway, if I understood correctly your question, try edit /etc/hosts putting 127.0.0.1:81 abc.com

Comment: So on abc host u need to redirect traffic from abc:80 to localhost:81 is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Forget iptables.

Do a `ssh -D 1234` to have a SOCKS proxy. Then you can configure your navigator to use this. (Or configure tsocks).

Of course you can also do it with iptables, but since you already have a ssh, it should be easier. Look for NAT and iptables keywords.

Comment: ssh i have used it to have a localport but i want to use iptables because i want to access that site without modifying any configuration on browser due i will access site with more programs than browser (for example a torrent program)